# Servicestack Query String

Tags: routes, servicestack

I Am trying to link values from a set query string to attributes in a service stack object.

The following code snippet illustrates what I am trying to achieve. (I want to map FN to SenderNumber, TN to ContactNumber etc.)

```
[Route("/smscallback?FN={SenderNumber}&TN={ContactNumber}&MS={Response}&TS={TS}")]
public class SmsCallback : IReturn<SmsCallbackResponse>
{
    public string SenderNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ContactNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Response
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string TS
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I have looked at the [routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) example servicestack provides but I am having trouble to  apply that to my situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Please re-read the [Routing wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing):

> Note: The QueryString, FormData and HTTP Request Body isn't apart of
>   the Route (i.e. only the /path/info is) but they can all be used in
>   addition to every web service call to further populate the Request
>   DTO.

You can't put **any queryString** in the route. If you want to change what the fields get mapped to you need to decorate your DTO with DataContract/DataMember attributes, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class SmsCallback : IReturn<SmsCallbackResponse>
{
    [DataMember(Name="fn")]
    public string SenderNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="tn")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="ms")]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What I ended up doing is to keep the [Route("/smscallback")] and then in the actual query string that gets sent the attribs get mapped eg. FN={SenderNumber}&TN={ContactNumber}.